# Dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 - Win8.1 (Can't boot Windows when UEFI mode is turned on)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, uefi, windows-8

I'm trying to install Ubuntu as a second OS, but I'm stuck at the `turn off secure boot` step.

I've found out that to disable secure boot I need to switch from Legacy mode to UEFI mode. But I can't start Windows when UEFI mode is turned on. That means I need to go back to Legacy mode which doesn't have an option to turn off secure boot. I'm confused.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **:-)** Just to be *absolutely* sure, could you [edit] your question and add the output to `sudo parted --list` in "try Ubuntu" mode in a terminal??? (Press [Ctrl][Alt][T] to open a terminal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't do anything**: apparently your Windows isn't installed in UEFI mode.

(This is the first time on this site I've told someone to not do anything!)

### :-)

Comment: Sounds great :) But how do I turn off secure boot then?

Comment: In the BIOS... :/

Comment: The option to turn off a secure boot is available only when I switch to UEFI mode

Comment: Then it *is* turned off automatically...  have you tried just skipping that step?

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: so how do I install Ubuntu alongside Windows with legacy mode?

Comment: Like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).  *If you would get stuck somewhere there*, just [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), and specify where exactly things go wrong...  **;-)**

Comment: I've already created a new one (https://askubuntu.com/questions/663333/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-legacy-mode)

Comment: Only one line..great :)

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate a bit on Fabby's answer:

Modern EFI/UEFI-based computers can usually boot either in native EFI/UEFI mode or using a feature called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables them to boot using older BIOS-mode boot loaders. This latter mode is often called "legacy mode," so it has three names: BIOS, CSM, and legacy; all mean the same thing in this context, and are distinct from native EFI/UEFI-mode booting.

Secure Boot is a UEFI feature that is active *only* in UEFI-mode booting. Thus, when you activate BIOS/CSM/legacy support, Secure Boot is either automatically deactivated or becomes relevant only for UEFI-mode boots, depending on the design of the firmware.

If your computer is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and refuses to boot when you switch the firmware to EFI/UEFI mode, then that implies that Secure Boot is *already* disabled, or at least bypassed, for booting Windows. Fabby asked for the output of `parted -l`, and that output will indicate Windows' boot mode with certainty. Specifically, Windows boots in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode *only* from MBR-partitioned (aka "MSDOS") disks, whereas it boots in EFI/UEFI mode *only* from GPT-partitioned disks. Thus, the disk type will indicate, with 100% certainty, what the current Windows boot mode is.

As a side note, any instructions that tell you to disable Secure Boot as a matter of course are suspect. Ubuntu has long supported Secure Boot, and should install just fine (in EFI/UEFI mode, of course) on most computers with Secure Boot active. Note the word "most," however; there are a few computers on which Ubuntu's Secure Boot support does not work. IMHO, those are best dealt with on a case-by-case basis rather than issuing instructions to disable Secure Boot on all computers.

Comment: As usual: much better then my answer...  I just couldn't resist answering "don't do anything!"...

Comment: So how do I install Ubuntu alongside Windows with legacy mode?

Comment: great answer bro, but I'm a little confused. My disk type is GPT which means my BIOS is on UEFI mode and I'm running dual-boot Ubuntu along with Windows 10, each time I power on my laptop I see the notification that says `Secure mode is off`. I thought that once is on UEFI mode, secure mode have to be in on state.

Comment: Secure Boot is an *optional* feature of UEFI. In fact, it's possible to disable Secure Boot on most UEFI-based computers that support it.